# How to block broadcast messages (Apple's mDNS traffic)

Tags: iptables, udp, multicast, mdns

I am in a network and a user is sending broadcast messages on udp port 5353. Regardless of what that is and what their purpose is, I decided to block all the traffic, so I ran:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 5353 -j DROP
```

But I am still getting the traffic (in wireshark), but with different source and destinations (neither the source nor the destination matches my IP). Apparently I need a mechanism to drop the broadcasts, is there any way of doing that using `iptables` or ufw?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to block this traffic?

Comment: Why shouldn't I block this traffic? There is no need to it, so I want to get rid of it. Secondly, and most importantly, there is security risk, which you can search and find out.

Comment: Why not simply drop all traffic to port 5353?    Why the complicated rule?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I was trying to do that.

Comment: Try `-I` (or `--insert`) instead of `-A` to get the rule placed at the front of the processing.

Comment: @meuh There shouldn't be any difference between `-A` or `-I num`. As far as I know, `-I` places the rule in a certain row of the chain table. Since there is no other rule specified in the table, it will automatically have the highest priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP cannot have state - try without the state clause.

Also, be aware that if you are checking incoming traffic with tcpdump, this listens OUTSIDE the firewall.

Comment: Tried that, but still getting the traffic: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j DROP
`

Comment: I'm checking the traffic using wireshark, is it also outside the firewall?

Comment: @emab you are right, wireshark sits between the hardware interface and iptables, so you will still see the packets arriving, before they are dropped by iptables.

Comment: Then the problem is probably solved, since I am monitoring the packets in wireshark.

Comment: @emab You can look at the number of packets matched by a rule with `iptables -L -nvx`.

Comment: @meuh Then it is working all good.

Comment: As far as I can tell, UDP 'state' can be handled with `-m conntrack --ctstate`, see http://www.iptables.info/en/connection-state.html

Comment: @amadanon-inc not exactly as you say....  need to distinguish between STATE-LESS and CONNECTION-LESS. UDP is connectionless but its session is stored in the session table of TCPIP stack and the same is used by iptables and conntrack.